# Amadeus - Command Cryptic - get taxes in country/city

Tags: amadeus

i'm trying to get informations about tax in specific country/city.

I need this because in availability from Amadeus i have price with tax or price without tax never together. Need to know what is net price. So i'm trying to get info about tax in city/country and calculate that on price with tax.

This is my query:

```
<Command_Cryptic>
    <messageAction>
        <messageFunctionDetails>
            <messageFunction>M</messageFunction>
        </messageFunctionDetails>
    </messageAction>
    <longTextString>
        <textStringDetails>FQNTAX/STO</textStringDetails>
    </longTextString>
</Command_Cryptic>
```

But this returns 39 pages :) maybe there is some option to get only hotel taxes with value ? or maybe somehow i can get this in easier way (need net price of reservation) ?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a bit more? 
Are you looking for tax information on flights or on hotels? 
Both flight and hotel search APIs provide basic tax information, is this what you're looking for? If not, what specific extra information do you need?

Comment: hello, i'm looking for tax information for hotels. I need to know tax in price. For example in MultiSingleAvailability i'm getting price after tax or price before tax. Never two at the same time are returning. So it will be good to know what are taxes in specific country/city to calculate price without tax for hotel.